# transaction error when explicit exception handling in spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I've found that there is a difference between being explicit and not having the same exception thrown.

1.

```
public class FooService {
    @Transactional
    public void foo() {
       try {
           fooRepository.save(foo); //  when DataIntegrityViolationException!!
       } catch(DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
          log.error("foo error");
       }
    }
}

public class Caller {

    public void caller() {
       try {
           fooService.foo();
       } catch(Exception e) {
          log.error("Caller error"); // happen
       }
    }
}
```

In the case of example 1, DataIntegrityViolationException occurs because it violates the constraint when saving.  In the log, a `caller error` is output and `Unexpect~Exception` is caught.

On the other hand, if an explicit DataIntegrityViolationException is thrown, no caller error is stamped.

2.

```
public class FooService {

    @Transactional
    public void foo() {
       try {
           fooRepository.save(foo); // when success
           if (true) {
               throw new DataIntegrityViolationException("ex");
           }
       } catch(DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
          log.error("foo error");
       }
    }
}

public class Caller {

    public void caller() {
       try {
           fooService.foo();
       } catch(Exception e) {
          log.error("Caller error"); // not logging
       }
    }
}
```

There is no difference when explicitly calling an exception in the Spring documentation. I wonder why this happened.

Comment: Because you are messing around with try/catch yourself whilst you shouldn't. In the first case, there is no error on save (I doubt the `foo error` message is displayed) and the error occurs on commit (after leaving the `foo()`). Your second one is thrown in the method and handled int he method, the TX code never sees the exception and just does a commit.

Comment: Please note that the examples are still experimental and the results are obvious. In the case of example 1, UnexpectedRollbackException occurs in the caller.

Comment: Because you catch the exception (I assumed JPA with flush-mode AUTO in your case which would trigger the exception after method execution) the tx code doesn't see the error and tries to commit, it cannot as the tx has been marked for rollback only leading to the `UnexpectedRollbackException`.

Comment: To summarize, is the reason UnexpectedRollbackException occurs because you are trying to commit? If so, I wonder if the exception UnexpectedRollbackException is not raised in.

Comment: That last comment doesn't really make any sense... Not sure what you want to convey? \